# What is the Fantasy font?

Tags: support, design

Several other questions discuss the design of Science Fiction and Fantasy SE UI elements, including the logo. The words "Science Fiction" are in Orbitron. What font is used for the word "Fantasy"?

Comment: [meta-tag:feature-request]: change the style sheet to show all sci-fi posts in Orbitron, and all fantasy posts in Polonaise. We’ll need a few more fonts to handle other gradations in genre.

Comment: @anaranjada [meta-tag:status-declined] I've already had to use the Stylish browser extension to get rid of as much of Orbitron from my view as possible.

Comment: I just asked Jin, who created the design for this site, directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The font is probably [Chopin Script](http://www.dafont.com/font-comment.php?file=chopin_script):

[image]

Comment: How did you generate that? The preview on myfonts.com put the F higher than that.

Comment: @anaranjada - I downloaded a version of Polonaise called Chopin Script.

Comment: Ah, no, wait, they are different.

Comment: They’re _very_ similar, and the text in the logo is too small to see some of the differences.

Comment: @anaranjada - Who knows? Maybe Chopin Script is a ripoff. It does look closer, though.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure, but it might be the font **Polonaise** (manufacturer URW).  See http://www.identifont.com/show?65F or http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/urw/polonaise/

Comment: Yes, I don’t see a difference in any letter of “Fantasy” or “meta”. It appears that the F in Fantasy was moved down somewhat though. The preview on myfonts.com shows the bottom of the F in line with the base of the other letters, while it hangs down in the logo.