# 'Fantasy' font too thin, detail getting lost

Tags: discussion, bug, design

I'm talking about the site logo/title (this applies to both meta and the main site, but I'm using meta as the example):

[image]

Specifically the 'F':

[image]

As you may be able to see, there's a top swooshy bit that gets really, *really* thin for about the rightmost half, to the point where at normal zoom on my monitor I can't see it. Without that part, the 'F' kinda looks more like a 'J'.

As this site is not 'Science Fiction and Jantasy', is this something that should be addressed/fixed?

For an example, here's a rough approximation of what it should look like, based on the lines that exist but are too small to see:

[image]

Comment: Except I know it's Sci-fi and Fantasy, so I would never read it as anything else

Comment: @Edlothiad Yeah, but just because you have a workaround doesn't mean you shouldn't fix something that's broken.

Comment: It's not broken. It looks fine

Comment: It's a fancy-looking logo, sure, but it doesn't scale for average-sized monitors. See my edit, by making the lines just a bit thicker all the intended detail is much easier to see.

Comment: I don't disagree, but it's hard to get anything considered a positive change on SE. Let alone something so low-profile.

Comment: @Axelord yeah, it does seem like I've insulted people by suggesting this. It's just something that, if I'd made a similar mistake, I'd want people to point out to me. In the spirit of the golden rule I thought I'd bring it up here.

Comment: No qualms from me. I even loosely support your argument. How are things, by the way?

Comment: @Axelord Of all the things relating to me, the only one of note is that I've been trying to get used to living off of less sleep. Turns out long-term effects include being bothered by small things. How about yourself?

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh Set in my sleep ways, set in my chat ways, enjoying life. Slapping the bull by talking here, but hey.

Comment: Could the font be better? Sure. Does it *need* fixing? No.

Comment: @phantom42 agreed, it's not going to kill anyone, but if the SE font guys aren't doing anything else, they might as well take a look.

Comment: They can have their [executive pastry chef](https://stackoverflow.com/company/team) bake a new logo.

Comment: I for one welcome our Science Fiction and Jantasy overlords

Comment: It's not a logo (our logo is that symbol everyone asks about). That F is just from a [pre-existing font](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9594/31178),  not something handmade by the designer.

Comment: @CreationEdge Tried to recreate logo. Summoned Baalzebub unto the world.

Comment: Anyway, I only mention it because I once remade the banner for https://thesffblog.com/ before SE allowed us to use the assets. It's not arduous, and someone could even make an image to be used in a userscript that overrides the CSS.

Comment: The logo a.k.a. the biohazardous Triforce.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh Well, there are at least five sites currently waiting for designs. I'd say that they're either busy or have quit.

Comment: I never noticed this before, but now that it's been pointed out it's to going to bug me horribly. Voting to change.

Comment: Maybe we ought to consider a design contest -- the SFF logo has been the same since I joined in November of 2011! We have contests for those little ads that go on other sites -- why not a contest for our site's background?

Answer (score 18):

I find the curlicue pointless and its being wider than the cross to be weird.
For the sake of brevity, I declare this F offensive.  Change it at once!

Seriously, it'd only be an image swap on the server.

Also, for the record, it looks more like a cursive T, and the curlicue is noticeable even though the cross isn't, so it looks more like Science and Tiantasy.

Comment: Boo for your opinion. It's Fantasy, we all know it. stop being silly.

Comment: @Edlothiad Boo for your alternative silly opinion. It's just kind of annoying, despite us all knowing it. Stop being silly.

Comment: Me being silly has nothing to do with the silly opinion you find being silly. If you think so then you're the one that's silly. It really isn't that annoying, I rarely look at it. Stop being silly.

Comment: @Edlothiad If we modeled all our nitpicks off of things average users paid attention to, there wouldn't be much of a site.

Comment: Its reminds me of Ford which when you looks closely is Feord.

Comment: Or Disney which I always thought looked like a backwards G

Comment: It should be fixed, somehow. It's just bad design; the font size is too small for that typeface.

Answer (score 1):

I like it and I don't think that it needs addressing.

Comment: You like that a part of the letter that's supposed to be there is too thin to see? Or you like the rest of it enough that it's not worth fixing?

Comment: @DaaaaahWhoosh - I find it perfectly comprehensible, thank you for asking

Comment: Comprehensibility isn't the issue here. Sure, you can read it, because the top part of the 'F' isn't necessary to tell what the letter is supposed to be. I just don't understand why you prefer your 'F's to be missing their top sections.

Comment: it's a typeface @DaaaahWhoosh - go look at any typeface repo and you'll find all manner of serif stylings. It's a non-issue in terms of actual typeface creation. If you don't like the particular typeface that's a different issue