# Can we rename this site to 'Science Fiction and Jantasy' to better reflect who we are?

Tags: feature-request, design

There seems to be a strange misunderstanding that we're called 'Science Fiction and Fantasy' where in fact we're called '**Science Fiction and Jantasy**, you can see it clearly in our [logo](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11183/21267).

So, **can we rename the site to reflect our *real* name?**

Comment: This seems a sensible and uncontroversial suggestion. You have my jull support.

Comment: I too am in javor of this change.

Comment: Why does everyone forget about the poor ampersand?

Comment: **Jcience Jiction and Jantasy** sound better and appropriate.

Comment: So, you don't want the logo changed, but the other way around..

Answer (score 13):

I, for second, welcome our Science Fiction and Jantasy overlords.

(Yoink!)

Answer (score 10):

Our site is most definitely called “Science Fiction & Fantasy”, you can see it clearly in our logo.

We've figured out what font is used for the “Fantasy” part in the thread [What is the Fantasy font?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9594/4918) , and “Jantasy” looks different from what we have in the site logo.

[image]

The above image shows “Jantasy” above and “Fantasy” below for comparison.  Compare them to the site logo and decide yourself.

Comment: The top one almost looks like "Santasy"  lol

Comment: @CreationEdge - [Santa:SE is go!](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1017/are-questions-about-santa-claus-on-topic)

Comment: Actually those two look *very* similar....